# Imputation with R and MICE

Tags: r, data-imputation

A short `mice`-related question as follows: when running simple [mice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html) imputation the function goes through well. But `complete()` function does not substitute my `NA`'s at all. I guess it must be something wrong with my dataset but I can't see what. It is just a matrix as any other although with roughly equal number of rows and columns. Maybe this is the source of the problem. What should I look into?

Comment: As Nick said, posting some sample data and code for what you're doing is necessary. As a wild guess, you're sure you didn't end up with "NA" as a string value instead of an actual NA?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this arises from including the original dataset. You can specify that by either choosing the `0` dataset or `complete(..., action="long", include=TRUE)`, see below example:

```
# Generate data
dat=data.frame(x1=c(21, 20, 31, 50), 
               x2=c(0, NA, 18, 3), 
               x3=c(0, 0, 54, 10))

library(mice)
# Do imputation
imp <- mice(dat, m=2)
```

Now this gives:

```
> # Look at the original dataset
> complete(imp, 0)
  x1 x2 x3
1 21  0  0
2 20 NA  0
3 31 18 54
4 50  3 10
> 
> # Get all the datasets
> complete(imp, action = "long", include = TRUE)
   .imp .id x1 x2 x3
1     0   1 21  0  0
2     0   2 20 NA  0
3     0   3 31 18 54
4     0   4 50  3 10
5     1   1 21  0  0
6     1   2 20  0  0
7     1   3 31 18 54
8     1   4 50  3 10
9     2   1 21  0  0
10    2   2 20 18  0
11    2   3 31 18 54
12    2   4 50  3 10
```